# Is there a way to port a git history of markdown files to mediawiki or alternatively just port the file structure of markdown files to mediawiki?

Tags: git, markdown, mediawiki, pandoc, pywikibot

Is there a way to port a git history of markdown files to mediawiki or alternatively just port the file structure of markdown files to mediawiki?

I have a project that I have been documenting using git and markdown. The project has gotten complicated enough to require a media wiki migration. I would prefer to port the git history to mediawiki and was wondering if this had been done before. While researching this problem I discovered portals from mediawiki to git but not the ability to import git to mediawiki. The project has hundreds of files written in markdown. Is there a way to port the git history with the markdown files to mediawiki? If that has not been done before is there a ready built tool to port the file structure of markdown files to mediawiki?

My plan otherwise would be to write my own python code using pandoc and pywikibot

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "the project has gotten complicated enough to require a media wiki integration"?

Comment: I have a folder of about 1000+ markdown files managed using git for said project. All markdown files are part of a tree structure with about 10 folders in the root folder going down about five levels deeper. It is cumber sum to link between these markdown files and it would be nice to add images and use other features built into mediawiki, especially semantic mediawiki.

It is my goal to port the tree structure and all the markdown files to my own semantic mediawiki deployment.

Comment: I've been working on an app - GitJournal - to make editing markdown files in Git repos easier. It also has images support. Maybe it will be useful. Though it's nowhere close to being a replacement for mediawiki.

Comment: You could try [git-remote-mediawiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Git-remote-mediawiki) or [Git2Pages](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Git2Pages) with `subst:`.

Comment: Thanks @Tgr this is what I was looking for

Comment: @Vishesh Handa can you send me a link to GitJournal it sounds like something I may be interested in using

Comment: It's https://gitjournal.io .